# Terraform plan not working for a long time with AWS S3

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform to deploy the backend code to AWS. While configuring the terraform environments, I typed the `terraform init`. It works fine, however, the next command - `terraform plan` is not working for a long time. The command doesn't tell anything. I am waiting for a long time but can't see any message from cli. I would love to get helped from you developers.

Here is my `main.tf` code.

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us_east_1"
  region = "us-east-1"

  default_tags {
    tags = {
      Owner   = "Example Owner"
      Project = "Example"
    }
  }
}

module "template_files" {
  source = "hashicorp/dir/template"

  base_dir = "react-app/build"

  template_vars = {
    vpc_id = "vpc-abc123123123"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test_tf_bucket" {
  bucket = local.test_tf_creds.bucket
  
  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
  }

  tags = {
    Bucket = "Example Terraform Bucket"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "build_test_tf" {
  for_each = module.template_files.files

  bucket = local.test_tf_creds.bucket
  key    = each.key
  content_type = each.value.content_type
  source = each.value.source_path
  content = each.value.content
  etag   = each.value.digests.md5

  tags = {
    Bucket-Object = "Example Bucket Object"
  }
}
```

I would love you developers to help me solve this problem.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10, 64bit.

Comment: I guess that's because they don't play well. Can you use WSL2 or GitBash instead?